# highcharts export server js script error codes

Tags: export, server-side, highcharts

I got the following error when I try to render charts on the server-side based on [this tutorial](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts).

```
phantomjs highcharts-convert.js -infile options1.json -outfile chart1.png -scale 2.5 -width 300 -constr Chart -callback callback.js
SyntaxError: Parse error

SyntaxError: Parse error

Highcharts.options.parsed
Highcharts.callback.parsed
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Highcharts

  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():58
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():103
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():103
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
```

The following are the files with hightcharts-convert.js file in the same directory.

```
 ls
callback.js            highcharts-more.js  highstock.js         options1.json
highcharts-convert.js  highcharts.js       jquery-1.8.2.min.js  readme.md
```

The content of options1.json

```
{
        xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        series: [{
                data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
};
```

The content of callback.js

```
function(chart) {
        chart.renderer.arc(200, 150, 100, 50, -Math.PI, 0).attr({
                fill : '#FCFFC5',
                stroke : 'black',
                'stroke-width' : 1
        }).add();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your highstock.js is a text file (not a binary file) !
The file http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js is gzipped ....

So here a detailled recipe :

Add 3 files in highcharts/exporting-server/phantomjs

```
cp js/highcharts.js exporting-server/phantomjs/
cp js/highcharts-more.js exporting-server/phantomjs/
curl http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js -o exporting-server/phantomjs/highstock.js.gz
```

Now decompressing the file :

```
gzip -d exporting-server/phantomjs/highstock.js.gz
```

If you go to the folder :

```
cd exporting-server/phantomjs/
```

You can check for md5 checksum (current version 2.3.5) :

```
4a656e1918e259fbca5bb3bec6e3b945  highcharts-convert.js
3e2a05342b0d4d1b759dffffebc5f23f  highcharts-more.js
d6f1e284bc49d0502576e06d905274fd  highstock.js
cfa9051cc0b05eb519f1e16b2a6645d7  jquery-1.8.2.min.js
1fde128c0c2f8bf16fa1a4166e9b48c7  readme.md
```

We could make a sample folder with files :

```
mkdir test
```

Put or create the two input files :

1st file : **callback.js**

```
function(chart) {
        chart.renderer.arc(200, 150, 100, 50, -Math.PI, 0).attr({
                fill : '#FCFFC5',
                stroke : 'black',
                'stroke-width' : 1
        }).add();
}
```

2nd file :  **infile.json**

```
{
        xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        series: [{
                data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
};
```

A sample test, here the command line from the test folder :

```
phantomjs  ../highcharts-convert.js -infile infile.json  -callback callback.js -outfile a.png -width 2400 -constr Chart -scale 1
```

The console result :

```
Highcharts.imagesLoaded:7a7dfcb5df73aaa51e67c9f38c5b07cb
done loading images
```

That all for this great library.

Xavier

Comment: you don't have to copy the file over if you don't want to create clutter and duplicates. you can change the reference to them to point to the correct file in `highcharts-convert.js`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is proper JSON:

```
{
    "xAxis": {
            "categories": ["Jan", "Feb","Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    },
    "series": [{
            "data": [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I changed the json part but still got the error `SyntaxError: Parse error

SyntaxError: Parse error

Highcharts.options.parsed
Highcharts.callback.parsed
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Highcharts

  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():58
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():103
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():103
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
loading images...
`

Answer (score 0):

In my case `highcharts.js` is a file missing.

This thing may help someone.